# Can I use Django with Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, django, next.js

I am new to Next.js and see that there is a `/api` folder. This seems like it **COULD replace my Django Rest Framework backend**. Is that what the `/api` folder is intended to do?

Moreover, is it common to see Django Rest Framework as a backend for Next.js? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next.js is a React framework therefore it is a client - which is responsible for getting data to a backend/server. The `api/` folder that you see could be any generic application programming interface folder considering you did not mention what was in its contents.

In a Next.js app that I have with an `api/` folder I have a `Stripe.ts` file that I reference to make api calls to Stripe services. That way I am separating my React code from Stripe code so to speak.

I have not used Django before, but I use Next.js **and** a Node server for a few of my applications.

edit: Next.js is a not a server if that answers your question in short.

Comment: Ahh got it. So if I have my backend (on Django or Node) with a `/login` endpoint for example, would I make the request in the `api/` folder? Or would I do it in one of my components?

Comment: Technically either, but recommended way is to configure the client to interface (connect and interact) with the server in a file like so `api/server.ts` and in the `/login` component use that interface. The reason why is because in another component in a different file at say `/getsomedata` you are not redefining the connection to your server and you are keeping your code separate. Let me know if you have any more questions I will help you find some examples.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that you are not "locked in" to structuring your interfaces in an api folder. If it makes sense to you, you could place all of your server code in a `/server` folder and in it have a `/config.ts` file where you connect to the server and `/auth.ts` file where you make all of your authentication calls. As far as I know the only Next.js reserved folder is `/pages`

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much for your help.